# Trouble displaying multiple Google Charts from different Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

This is my first question/cry for help on my account. This is my first real foray in to a javascript library besides simple plug and play. With that said...

I am looking to build a user dashboard that pulls from a Google Spreadsheet source with different query's for each data visualization.

However, I am currently stuck with trying to display more than one Google Charts visualization per page. While I am currently just seeking to display more than one Google Charts visualization, in the future the dashboard page will hold several Google Charts visualizations. With that said, that code is posted below. I understand that I need to create a new query for each spreadsheet or spreadsheet query I am pulling from, but I am having trouble figuring out how to draw more than a single graph on the page.

The code below is what I have now...It currently draws no graphs, but I can get it to draw just one with a few edits.

Here is a link to the current page:
http://brentocreates.com/ziftydata/

Let me know what I'm missing. 
Thank you in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Zifty Driver Data</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/navbar-static-top.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/zifty.css">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

    <!--Load Graphing/Charting JS -->
    <script src="js/Chart.Core.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Chart.Bar.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->



    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>




    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", '1', {packages:['corechart']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
          var queryHourly = new google.visualization.Query(
              'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yg7mmdMNkuxFIQ67j4d-digf0qwh4TeEfyBrHIcH5KA/edit?usp=sharing');

          queryHourly.send(handleQueryResponse); 

          var queryMileage = new google.visualization.Query(
              'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yg7mmdMNkuxFIQ67j4d-digf0qwh4TeEfyBrHIcH5KA/edit?usp=sharing');

          queryMileage.send(handleQueryResponse);
        }        

        function handleQueryResponse(response1, response2) {
          if (response1.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response1.getMessage() + ' ' + response1.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
          }

          if (response2.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response2.getMessage() + ' ' + response2.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
          }


          var dataHourly = response1.getDataTable();
          var chartHourly = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('hourlychart'));
          chartHourly.draw(dataHourly, { legend: { position: 'none' } });

          var dataMileage = response2.getDataTable();
          var chartMileage = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('mileagechart'));
          chartMileage.draw(dataMileage, { legend: { position: 'none' } });
        }
  </script>  
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Zifty Driver Dashboard</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Static top</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
                <h3>Average Hourly per Day of the Week</h3>
                <span id="hourlychart"></span>
          </div>

         <div class="col-md-5">
                <h3>Average Mileage per Day of the Week</h3>
                <span id="mileagechart"></span>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
          <hr />
      </div>
      <!-- Main component for displaying graphs -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Average Hourly vs. Mileage, per DotW</h1>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```